# Find all artifacts with a common dependency

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket, nexus, bitbucket-server

I'd like to find all of my projects that have one particular dependency, much like Mvnrepository.com "usages" feature.

Our projects are all Java with Maven-based builds, and all of our artifacts are published to a local Nexus repository. Most of our projects can be found on a Bitbucket Server installation, though not all.

Can anyone recommend a way of doing so?

Comment: Parse the output from `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I could go over every project and do that, but then _I_ would be doing all the work, not the computer.

Comment: I am currently building a Neo4j database from the dependency data of our projects to answer requests like the one you stated. I do not know any immediate way to do it.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral The computer does the work.  You just need some scripting glue.  If you are looking for an online service to do that for you, your best bet may be to tell mvnrepository that your projects exist.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I cannot make the few hundred projects in my company public, so that's not an option. Cloning and checking out every repository to run dependency:tree on all submodules is too error prone to script reliably, so I'll have to keep writing special cases, will miss projects on Bitbucket, and does not make use at all of the dependency information present on Nexus. Looks to me like me doing all the work, not the computer.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral So you are basically asking for a tool or software recommendation.   Will you close and delete your question yourself for being off-topic?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It's not off topic. I use Bitbucket Server, I use Nexus, the question is tagged with both. How do I do that using the things I have? What in Bitbucket Server and/or Nexus will allow me to do so? _Your_ comment is off-topic in that it's completely ignoring the content of my question and suggesting things outside its scope.

Comment: We had to develop a custom solution using Kibana Discover, ElasticSearch, ModDB and our internal artifacts server: artifactory. We also used jenkins to do the indexing.